# EJB @Stateless and @WebService on Websphere 7

Tags: java, jax-ws, ejb-3.0, websphere-7

I am looking all over the place to try and figure out how to turn a stateless session bean into a JAX-WS webservice (I am using WAS 7, Websphere Integration Developer, EJB 3).  Not Jax-RPC.  I am officially sick and tired of messing around with the wizard that comes with WID.  Fore some reason it simply won't let me do that...  I have tried creating a JAX-WS webservice from a Java bean, In other words, I created a Java class and ran the wizard on that thing, and it created a whole new Project...

Is there a tutorial out there somewhere that will just give me what I need to know to create this Webservice without having to use the wizard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the The Java EE 5 Tutorial try [A Web Service Example: helloservice - The Java EE 5 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbor.html).

Others:

- [EJB and Web Services: getting the best of both worlds](http://veithen.github.io/2009/11/15/ejb-and-web-services.html)
- [Java EE 6/7: The Lean Parts](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvtuFLz2prk), a conference in JavaOne
- [Samples > Web services](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.webservice.was.samples.ejb.doc/topics/wsejb_sample.html), from IBM

---

### Example

I wrote a small sample application.

#### Structure  of Projects

```
`-- HelloEAR
|   |-- .project
|   `-- .settings
|       |-- org.eclipse.wst.common.component
|       |-- org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
`-- HelloEJB
|   `-- .apt_generated
|   |   `-- org
|   |       `-- paulvargas
|   |           `-- ejb
|   |               `-- jaxws
|   |                   |-- SayHello.java
|   |                   |-- SayHelloResponse.java
|   |-- .classpath
|   |-- .factorypath
|   |-- .project
|   `-- .settings
|   |   |-- org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.prefs
|   |   |-- org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
|   |   |-- org.eclipse.wst.common.component
|   |   |-- org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
|   `-- ejbModule
|   |   `-- META-INF
|   |   |   |-- ibm-webservices-bnd.xmi
|   |   `-- org
|   |   |   `-- paulvargas
|   |   |       `-- ejb
|   |   |           |-- HelloBean.class
|   |   |           |-- HelloBean.java
|   |   |           |-- HelloLocal.class
|   |   |           |-- HelloLocal.java
|   |   |           |-- HelloRemote.class
|   |   |           |-- HelloRemote.java
|   |   |           `-- jaxws
|   |   |               |-- SayHello.class
|   |   |               |-- SayHelloResponse.class
`-- HelloWeb
|   `-- .apt_generated
|   |-- .classpath
|   |-- .factorypath
|   |-- .project
|   `-- .settings
|   |   |-- .jsdtscope
|   |   |-- org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.prefs
|   |   |-- org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
|   |   |-- org.eclipse.wst.common.component
|   |   |-- org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
|   |   |-- org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.container
|   |   |-- org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.name
|   `-- src
|   `-- WebContent
|   |   `-- WEB-INF
|   |       `-- classes
|   |       `-- lib
|   |       |-- web.xml
```

[image]

#### HelloBean.java

```
package org.paulvargas.ejb;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@Stateless
@WebService
public class HelloBean implements HelloRemote, HelloLocal {
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        return "Hello, " + name + ".";
    }
}
```

#### HelloRemote.java

```
package org.paulvargas.ejb;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface HelloRemote {
    String sayHello(String name);
}
```

#### HelloLocal.java

```
package org.paulvargas.ejb;

import javax.ejb.Local;

@Local
public interface HelloLocal {
    String sayHello(String name);
}
```

#### ibm-webservices-bnd.xmi

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<com.ibm.etools.webservice.wsbnd:WSBinding
    xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI"
    xmlns:com.ibm.etools.webservice.wsbnd="http://www.ibm.com/websphere/appserver/schemas/5.0.2/wsbnd.xmi">
    <routerModules transport="http" name="HelloWeb.war" />
</com.ibm.etools.webservice.wsbnd:WSBinding>
```

#### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>HelloWeb</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>org.paulvargas.ejb.HelloBean</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>org.paulvargas.ejb.HelloBean</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/HelloBeanService</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Files `SayHello.java` and `SayHelloResponse.java` are generated automatically by the IDE.
You can see the deployed WSDL file in `http://localhost:9080/HelloWeb/HelloBeanService/HelloBeanService.wsdl`

Comment: Might just support your excellent references with a short code snippet showing use of the annotation

Comment: I added an example to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This is much more than I would have expected.  Well done.